# Self contained Kotlin/Gradle project produces java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

Can anyone help me please? I need to setup a **completely** offline IntelliJ project with gradle and kotlin for our constrained school environment (No Kotlin installed, No Gradle installed, No Internet).

I packed all kotlin dependencies into libs/kotlin but it still tells me, that kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics is not found. You can find the repo here:

```
Could not perform incremental compilation: Could not connect to Kotlin compile daemon
Could not connect to kotlin daemon. Using fallback strategy.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler$Companion.main(K2JVMCompiler.kt)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.main(K2JVMCompiler.kt)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics
```

You can checkout the repo here:
https://github.com/emign/kotlinOfflineTest

Comment: cannot open repository - 404, think it's closed